# Is every monomorphism a homonomorphism?

Tags: abelian-categories, triangulated-categories

Let $\mathcal T$ be a pre-triangulated category, $u:X\to Y$ a morphism. Then $u$ is a homonomorphism if its homotopy kernel is $0,$ i.e. there exists a distinguished triangle of the form $$X\overset{u}{\to}Y\to Z\overset{0}{\to}\Sigma X.$$ My question is:

> Is every monomorphism a homonomorphism?

For a monomorphism, I know there exists a diagram:
$$\begin{array}{ccccccc} X & \overset{u}{\to} & Y & \to & \Sigma T & \overset{\Sigma t}{\to} & \Sigma X \\
\parallel & & \parallel & & \downarrow v & & \parallel \\
X & \overset{u}{\to} & Y & \to & \Sigma K & \overset{0}{\to} & \Sigma X
\end{array},$$
where the first row is a distinguished triangle, and my question would be answered if the morphism on the third column is an isomorphism.

**Thoughts:**
I don't see why the second row is a distinguished triangle, so that we cannot apply some theorems about pretriangulated categories. In fact, our goal is to show that it *is* a triangle.
I tried to prove that $v$ is an isomorphism by the universal properties of the kernel and the homotopy kernel. But, while I can show that $v$ is an epimorphism, I cannot show that it is a monomorphism, since factorisations through homotopy kernels are not unique.

Any hints, suggestions, or references are sincerely welcomed.

Comment: In the derived category of chain complexes, the homotopy kernel is zero if and only if the morphism is a quasi-isomorphism.

Comment: I doubt it is true though I haven't any counterexample. Two reasons : I don't expect that monomorphisms have good properties in a triangulated category, and secondly every homonomorphism is a monomorphism, thus, if the converse were true, there will be no point in calling it a homonomorphism instead of a monomorphism.

Comment: In fact, my question is motivated by [this note](http://therisingsea.org/notes/TriangulatedCategories.pdf), in which the proposition $12.$ says exactly that being a homonomorphism is equivalent with a monomorphism. And it says in the discussion preceding Remark $12.$ that **It is obvious that any monomorphism is a homonomorphism, and any epimorphism
is a hoepimorphism.** This confuses me, so i post here. And thanks for the attention.

Comment: @awllower Ok then, it is good to know. I should have thought a little bit before commenting. So in fact, consider a distinguished triangle $X \overset{u}\rightarrow Y\rightarrow C\rightarrow X[1]$ with $u$ a monomorphism. The morphism $C[-1]\rightarrow X$ from the triangle and the zero morphism $C[-1]\rightarrow X$ are the same after composing with $u:X\rightarrow Y$. Because $u$ is a monomorphism, they must be equal. Hence $u$ is a homonomorphism.

Comment: @user113969 Ah ha! Thanks for pointing this *obvious* fact out. And you can post the comment, maybe somewhat modified, as an answer, and I shall accept that. Great thanks again. To Mr. Zhen Lin: Also thanks for the interesting proposition about derived categories. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $u:X\rightarrow Y$ is a monomorphism and consider a cone $C$ of $u$ so that we have an exact triangle
$$X\overset{u}\rightarrow Y\rightarrow C\rightarrow \Sigma X$$
The map $\Sigma^{-1}C\rightarrow X$ coming from the triangle coincide with the zero map $\Sigma^{-1}C\rightarrow X$ after composing with $u$. Because $u$ is a monomorphism, they are equal. Hence $u$ is homonomorphism.